# How to access/ mock jquery for angular unit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing

I do not have the ability to remove jQuery from being used in the the directives that I am testing.

This line of code is causing me problems

```
$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $('.ng-invalid:not(form.ng-invalid):first').offset().top - 140 }, 'slow');
```

In my console i am getting back

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`
```

To get around this I am hoping to mock out jquery calls.

In my karma.conf I have jQuery loaded

```
files: [
    'lib/jquery-*.js',
```

However, when I use a library like **bard js** to mock out jquery

```
bard.mockService($, {
   _default: $q.when({})
})
```

I get back $ is not defined.   Is there a way to mock out jquery so that it is not called and I can run my tests?

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but if that element on which you're calling offset() has display:none the offset will be undefined as per the big yellow sticky note on [this page](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)  That seems to be a pretty good fit for the error message.

Comment: I looked through the project.  Didn't find that to be the case but it would have made sense.

Comment: Was able to pass by simply adding class=\"ng-invalid\" to my mocked angular element along with jQuery     element.appendTo(document.body);